# Cache-uncache property

Tags: python

Is there some way to cache properties only up to the moment when some of the input attributes of the class instance is changed? I want to recalculate cached properties (and cache them again) when they are called after some of the input attributes of the class instance had been updated.

If I have a class like this:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a

    @cached_property
    def expensive(self):
        return 'some calculation which depends on the attribute "a"'

    def dependent(self):
        return 'some calculation which depends on the "C.expensive"'
```

When I call C.dependent for the first time it will call C.expensive and cache its output for future calls. If I update my instance with C.a=new_value, and than call C.dependent, I want to update C.expensive and cache it again until new update of the instance.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code that they can reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about "properties" but since you are mentioning input parameters I think that you are actually referring to methods, therefore you can use [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator

Example:

```
@lru_cache
def count_vowels(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.casefold()
    return sum(sentence.count(vowel) for vowel in 'aeiou')
```

For properties there is [functools.cached_property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)

Answer (score 0):

I found that `@lru_cache` provides a `cache_clear()` function for clearing or invalidating the cache, which is exactly what I need. This function can be called in the setter of the class attribute and this will clear the cache every time the attribute is updated. As far as I can see, `@cached_property` does not provide this option.